# Tomcat6 on Windows: Looking for command to start service

Tags: tomcat

I am currently starting my Tomcat6 service (on Windows) via "Tomcat Monitor" - which means clicking on the tray icon (see pic):

[image: Starting tomcat]

I'd like to this via command line, but I can't figure out the correct command.
This is what my configuration looks like:

[image: Tomcat config]

Does anyone know the correct command to start Tomcat6 as service according to this settings? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from the command prompt you can do `net start [your tomcat service name]`

to stop it you do `net stop [your tomcat service name]`

the default service name is Tomcat6, unless you changed it when you installed tomcat.